# Queue command in Asterisk 13 with gosub argument?

Tags: asterisk

I believe in Asterisk 13 Queue command can specify gosub so it will gosub on the called party's channel (the queue member) once the parties are connected.
But how to pass the args to gosub?

I tried:

```
exten => _X.,n,Queue(queue1,,,180,,,setstartcall,s,1(arg_callstarted,${UNIQUEID}))
```

But it is not working, i'm not getting the argument in my sub context.

```
[setstartcall]
exten => s,1,Set(DB(${ARG1}/${ARG2})=${EPOCH})
exten => s,n,Return()
```

Comment: All variables should be attached to channel and you should not pass them, they just should be there.

Comment: what if I really want to pass the args?

Comment: I get your point. I also can do other ways to fullfill my need. But in general, since GoSub allows you to pass the arguments, what the purpose of it here if you should not using it?

Comment: I think args should not always be assigned to global variables.

Comment: If you really want pass arg, pass it as part of extension(number), like s-${VAR} and parse in dialplan.

Answer (score 0):

You should use parent channel variable setup.

```
exten => _X.,n,Set(__ARG_1=${UNIQUEID}); double underline mean set this variable to same for any child channel created.
```

Put that before queue

Comment: This is just work around. So gosub in Queue command is not like GoSub() app which allows to passing args to sub context?

Comment: That clearly state in app queue description. Only 3 arguments expected.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on arheops's answer, you can use variable inheritance to pass variables down through the stack, which is outlined here, https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Variable+Inheritance

So as they explained, you can set a variable prefaced with two underscores for it to be inherited by any new channels created, which means it could be set as `__FOO` and then referenced later as `${FOO}`.

Therefore to combine your example and their answer:

```
[incoming] ; Using 'incoming' as the parent context
exten => _X.,n,Set(__UNIQ=${UNIQUEID})
exten => _X.,n,Queue(queue1,,,180,,,setstartcall))

[setstartcall]
exten => s,1,Set(DB(arg_callstarted/${UNIQ})=${EPOCH})
exten => s,n,Return()
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use arguments in the gosub param of Queue app this way :

```
exten => _X.,n,Queue(queue1,,,180,,,"setstartcall,arg_callstarted,${UNIQUEID}")
```

Found the answer in the code : https://github.com/asterisk/asterisk/blob/6222e73cd8085112f4cfa94621e937ebce2835f9/apps/app_queue.c#L7349